# Program to remove a specified character from a string - empty spaces causes assert to fail

Tags: arrays, c, char

I'm attempting to remove a given character from a string and for the most part my code is working, however when I specify "" as the string and ' ' as the character, my assert fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void strrem(const char* s1, const char c, char* s2);

int main(void)
{

   char str[1000];

   strrem("abc", 'b', str); assert(strcmp(str,"ac")==0);
   strrem("ABC", 'a', str); assert(strcmp(str,"ABC")==0);
   strrem("Hello World!", '!', str); assert(strcmp(str,"Hello World")==0);
   strrem("", ' ', str); assert(strcmp(str,"")==0);

   return 0;
}

void strrem(const char* s1, const char c, char* s2)
{
   int i, j;
   int strlngth = strlen(s1);


   for (i = 0, j = 0; i < strlngth; i++) {
      if(s1[i] != c) {
         s2[j++] = s1[i];
      }


      s2[j] = '\0';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of constantly assigning the nullbyte every loop then overwriting it, just assign it after the loop, which also fixes your issue (which is not assigning the nullbyte when your code never loops):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

void strrem(const char* s1, const char c, char* s2);

int main(void)
{

   char str[1000];

   strrem("abc", 'b', str); assert(strcmp(str,"ac")==0);
   strrem("ABC", 'a', str); assert(strcmp(str,"ABC")==0);
   strrem("Hello World!", '!', str); assert(strcmp(str,"Hello World")==0);
   strrem("", ' ', str); assert(strcmp(str,"")==0);

   return 0;
}

void strrem(const char* s1, const char c, char* s2)
{
   int i, j;
   int strlngth = strlen(s1);


   for (i = 0, j = 0; i < strlngth; i++) {
      if(s1[i] != c) {
         s2[j++] = s1[i];
      }


   
   }
   // this is now after the loop
   s2[j] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Well that is frustratingly simple. Thank you for the answer